# Cursor vs. set-based solutions for data manipulation tasks

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm reading the training kit for exam-70-461 Querying SQL Server 2012.

Page 604 gives an example, and I was testing it but it does not work... any suggestions?

example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.GetNums', N'IF') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION  dbo.GetNums;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetNums (@low as bigint, @high as bigint) RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
WITH
    L0 as (SELECT c from (VALUES(1), (1)) as D(c)),
    L1 as (SELECT 1 as c FROM L0 as A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
    L2 as (SELECT 1 as c FROM L1 as A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
    L3 as (SELECT 1 as c FROM L2 as A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
    L4 as (SELECT 1 as c FROM L3 as A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
    L5 as (SELECT 1 as c FROM L4 as A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),
    Nums as (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as rownum
            FROM L5)
SELECT @low + rownum - 1 as n
FROM Nums
ORDER BY rownum
OFFSET 0 ROWS 
FETCH FIRST @high - @low + 1 ROWS ONLY;
GO
```

Error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GetNums, Line 17
>   Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'.
>   Msg 153, Level 15, State 2, Procedure GetNums, Line 18
>   Invalid usage of the option FIRST in the FETCH statement.

Comment: I would guess that you're not running against a SQL Server **2012** engine here - what is the result of `SELECT @@VERSION` ?? `OFFSET & FETCH` are new features in the 2012 version

Comment: Oops.. Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM)..
Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code above produces the error message when run in SQL Server 2008 R2, but runs successfully in SQL Server 2012.

OFFSET and FETCH are [new features in 2012](http://dbadiaries.com/new-t-sql-features-in-sql-server-2012-offset-and-fetch).

Comment: Was running Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM)..
Thank you! :)